# I try to use JMeter to create user journey but end up with error code 428

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am currently trying to use JMeter to create an User Journey which emulates user experience in WizzAir.com. However when I perform a search (post request), the script creates error. I have no clue how to solve this issue, can someone help. Thanks

[image: Result]

I recorded the User Journey with BlazeMeter, copy and pasted the request headers from Google dev tools and ensured the `x-requestverificationtoken` is created by the script instead of hardcoded. Still, the result shows code 428.